# WPF DataGrid Scrollbar resizes in funny ways

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, scrollbar

I use a WPF DataGrid which contains various rows each of which can have a different height. When I scroll the grid, the scrollbar changes its size. I think this is because of the different row-heights. Is there a way to fix this, so that the scrollbar doesn't change its size while scrolling?

Comment: can u knock up quick XAML for that problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you probably resolved this by now but I had the same issue and added

```
  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
```

to my DataGrid attributes in XAML

Comment: The reason: this changes to physical scrolling and this in turn disables Virtualization and that makes all row heights known.